# Location changed handler not callled

Tags: android, geolocation, gps

I am working on an app that relies on GPS signal (no mobile data is available) and I am trying to receive location updates.

```
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // Show an alert
}
```

When I set my Android device location to use both GPS and Network. I receive location updates but if I use GPS only `onLocationChanged` is not called.

Comment: Check edited code!

Answer (score 0):

You should get all providers of location, your code only get from NETWORK_PROVIDER and not get from GPS_PROVIDER:

```
    List<String> providers = mLocationManager.getProviders(true);
    for (String s : providers) {

        if (provider.equalsIgnoreCase(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            mGPSOn = true;
            //curLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        }
        if (provider.equalsIgnoreCase(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            mNetworkOn = true;
            //curLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        }
    }
    if (mNetworkOn) {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, GeoTraceGoogleMapActivity.this);
    }

    if (mGPSOn) {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, GeoTraceGoogleMapActivity.this);
    }
```

Comment: But NETWORK_PROVIDER is get final should location was received from NETWORK_PROVIDER and ignore GPS_PROVIDER.

Comment: But your code does the same. It iterates through the providers' names and set the listener. Correct me if I am wrong.